# Admob/Appodeal Ad banner under every 10 articles

Tags: java, android, listview, admob, appodeal

I am developing an Android Application written in Java. On the Home page of the app I am showing a number of N articles in a ListView. I implemented Appodeal Ads successfully and now I was thinking that I want to show an ad banner under every 10 articles. How can I do this, in a "legal" way?

I have an idea of how to do it, but I want to be sure it is legal and not have to display 50, or so, different ads to every user and get 50 impressions for only a user. I want to show the same ad 5, or so, times.

Every answer is welcomed. Thank you!

Comment: You can display as many ads you want. Its legal. But while considering user experience limit the number of ads. Otherwise if your app shows many ads the users may not suggest or use your application

Comment: Ok, I will keep this in mind. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can display as many ads you want. Its legal. But while considering user experience limit the number of ads. Otherwise if your app shows many ads the users may not suggest or use your application